chromedriver not render the web scrapping data
I am trying to scrape a website data using python.
I am using selenium version 4.20.0
I haven't installed chromedriver in my system. however my script was running just fine using just chrome.
After .91 update when I run the script my chrome is still working but it's just not rendering any data.
only "data;" keeps showing on tab as well as on url search input box.
below is my code and screenshot of data not rendering.
import configparser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException, StaleElementReferenceException
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import time
import os
import logging

# Get the download path for the current user
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='app.log', level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

def run_script(config):

    config.read('credentials.ini')
    # Load the workbook
    book  = config ['Credentials']['saveFilePath']
    wb = load_workbook(book)
    ws = wb.active
    # Clear the sheet
    ws.delete_rows(2, ws.max_row)
    # Find the next empty row in the worksheet
    next_row = ws.max_row + 1

    username = config['Credentials']['username']
    password = config['Credentials']['password']
    AgencyFilePath = config['Credentials']['AgencyFilePath']
    workbook = load_workbook(AgencyFilePath)
    sheet = workbook.active

    try: 
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()

        login_url = 'https://www.google.com'
        driver.get(login_url)

        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

        username_field = wait.until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="lock-title"]'))
        )

        # Find the username and password input fields and submit button by class name
        username_field = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="1-email"]' #xpath of username field
        ).send_keys(username)

        password_field = driver.find_element(
            By.XPATH, '//*[@id="1-password"]' #Xpath of password field
        ).send_keys(password)

image of problem

Provide more details about your issue and also provide code for it, it helps a lot, as you are new please view this StackOverflow Page on How To Write Good Questions on Stack Overflow.

Hi, I've edited the post.  if you able to figure out what's the issue. Thanks for your help in advance

You need to download both chrome and chromedriver from the Chrome for Testing page.
And instead of Webdriver.Chrome(), use the below code:
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(chrome_driver_path)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = chrome_binary_path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

Download same version of chrome and chromedriver, and add their path in the script.
